# PHP Nested for-each loop

Tags: php, foreach

```
$QRYS1 = QUERY;
$QRYS2 = QUERY;
$QRYS3 = QUERY;
$QRYS4 = QUERY;

foreach($QRYS1 as $QRY1)
{
 foreach($QRYS2 as $QRY2)
 {
   if(bla)
   {
   foreach($QRYS3 as $QRY3)
   {
     foreach($QRYS4 as $QRY4)
     {

     }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

The above style of code makes data processing very slow. Is there anyway I can make the processing fast?

I am getting the data doing joining and counting with multiple tables and its all ARRAY().

Comment: Without knowing more about your database, your data and several other things it would be impossible to answer. It is very likely that you can issue one query properly joined, for instance, rather than 4 discrete queries.

Comment: `$QRYS* = QUERY;` What is the meaning? It's array data OR MySQL Query?

Comment: well my DB is MySQL and as for data they are simple but when it comes to joining and doing counting where process becomes very slow.

Comment: @jay: for example, I got 400 user who are grouped in 15 departments and each user can be linked to 6 different products and each departments can be linked to 6 different products, in this way I got 50 companies with 1500 users and each companies has 10 to 20 departments and all of them can be linked to Product list (6 different)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$TotalCountofDepartmentforSelectedComp_id = Userlog::where('userlogs.company_id', '=', $comp_id)
    ->where_Between('userlogs.created_at', $startDate, $endDate)
    ->group_by('userlogs.department_id')
    ->get(['userlogs.department_id', DB::raw('count(userlogs.user_id) as totaldepartmentcount')]);

$ProductListforSelectedComp_id = Product::join('userlogs', 'userlogs.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
    ->where('userlogs.company_id', '=', $comp_id)
    ->distinct()
    ->get(['products.id', 'products.name']);


$TotalCountCompanyProductWiseinforSelectedComp_id = Product::join('userlogs', 'userlogs.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
    ->where('userlogs.company_id', '=', $comp_id)
    ->where_Between('userlogs.created_at', $startDate, $endDate)
    ->group_by('products.id')
    ->get(['products.id', DB::raw('count(userlogs.user_id) as totalcompanyproductcountuserwise')]);

$DepartmentListsforSelectedComp_id = Department::where('company_id', '=', $comp_id)->get(
    ['departments.id', 'departments.name']
);


$TotalCountCompanyDepartmentProductWiseinforSelectedComp_id = DB::query(
    'SELECT T1.id, T2.department_id,
            COALESCE(T2.totaldepartmentproductcountuserwise, 0) AS totaldepartmentproductcountuserwise
       FROM (
         SELECT DISTINCT products.id FROM products
           INNER JOIN userlogs ON userlogs.product_id = products.id
           WHERE company_id = ?
         ) AS T1
       LEFT JOIN (
         SELECT department_id, product_id, COUNT(*) AS totaldepartmentproductcountuserwise
           FROM userlogs
           WHERE company_id = ?
             AND created_at BETWEEN ? AND ?
           GROUP BY department_id, product_id
         ) AS T2 ON T2.product_id = T1.id',
    array($comp_id, $comp_id, $startDate, $endDate));
```

Comment: its Laravel! The above code is as much as I can go with advance SQL, still learning, please help

Answer (score 4):

fetching table using for-each loop will slow down your page. You can try joining of tables and fetch those fields which you want.

Comment: Joins and groups are probably going to be necessary here

Comment: I have given a sample of my SQL below

Comment: Manage Index in your table structure for fast query processing.